# JS files are not updating in Pub/Static Folder and JS files are also not listing in Source tab of crome in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, pub

I am trying to change the code of JS file in my module but it's not updating in the pub/static folder. when am I checking the source tab of crome it's also not listing under it.

I am following the below step to update module JS to the pub/static folder.

1. After Changes in Module, JS files run following command

> `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_SA en_GB en_US`

2. after running this command running - `php bin/magento cache: clean` & `flush`
3. after that putting permission 777 
   But I did not get any changes in that file in pub/static folder.

I am using **Ngnix** and **Redis** Cache for my website

Thanks for your support in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the static files before, running `setup:upgrade` before.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_SA en_GB en_US
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I have tried this many times. code is updating in js files now but not reflecting on frontend . I have enabled bundling. is it causing me?

Comment: Hi @SarveshTiwari, not reflecting on the frontend is related to another question.